# How to query pass 2 of multiple conditions

Tags: django

I need query objects passed 2 of multiple conditions. Example:
We have a model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    cost = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    quality = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

Conditions:

- cost < 5
- price < 7
- quality > 0
- ...
- code = 1234
- `name` contains 'apple'

Result can be:
- 'C' item with cost = 6, price = 6, quality = 2, code = 321, name = 'asd asdsd'
- 'D' with value: cost=4, price=6, quality=2, code=322, name='xyz'

How to query item passed as less 2 conditions?

Comment: `A.objects.filter(cost__lt=5, price__lt=7 ..... so on )` You can use this In django

Comment: What do you mean with "as less"?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem "as less" means the item only need passed 2 of n conditions

Comment: You can use `Q` to OR the queries

Comment: @CharanjitSingh your way just query all item passed all conditions. This isn't my expect

Comment: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/query_relatedtool.html

Comment: @CharanjitSingh If you use `Q` to OR the queries, the item can be passed only 1 condition. I want it passed 2 or more conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can first annotate with the number of conditions that are satified, and then filter on that number:

```
from django.db.models import Q, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

A.objects.annotate(
    nvalid=Cast(Q(cost__lt=5), output_field=IntegerField()) +
           Cast(Q(price__lt=7), output_field=IntegerField()) +
           Cast(Q(quality__gt=0), output_field=IntegerField()) +
           Cast(Q(code='1234'), output_field=IntegerField()) +
           Cast(Q(name__contains='apple'), output_field=IntegerField())
).filter(nvalid__gte=2)
```